# OBIEE -- Syntax Error with Substring?

Tags: analysis, obiee

I'm looking at the following code as an edit to a field formula in an OBIEE analysis, yet returns an error. Any thoughts?

```
SUBSTRING("Dim - Vendor Header"."Dock Time", 
LOCATE(':',"Dim - Vendor Header"."Dock Time")+1, 
  (CHAR_LENGTH("Dim - Vendor Header"."Dock Time") - 
LOCATE(':',REVERSE("Dim - Vendor Header"."Dock Time")) - 
LOCATE(':',"Dim - Vendor Header"."Dock Time")))
```

The error follows:

```
Formula syntax is invalid.
[nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. [nQSError: 43113] Message 
returned from OBIS. [nQSError: 27002] Near <)>: Syntax error [nQSError: 
26012] .Please have your System Administrator look at the log for more 
details on this error. (HY000)
SQL Issued: SET VARIABLE DISABLE_CACHE_HIT=1; SELECT Substring ("Dim - 
Vendor Header"."Dock Time", LOCATE(':',"Dim - Vendor 
Header"."Dock Time")+1) FROM "XHSS - Vendor"
OK (Ignore Error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any function string REVERSE in obiee12c ?
Can you please try by giving only below part in formula, and check the same error is getting...

(CHAR_LENGTH("Dim - Vendor Header"."Dock Time") - LOCATE(':',REVERSE("Dim - Vendor Header"."Dock Time"))